# jquery addon for slider shown onclick

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Is there a addon/plugin for jQuery that works the same as [timepicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) but can be set as percentage instead of time...

I'm looking for functionality that allows users to use a slider to set the progress of a task after clicking on a input element.

Answer (score 1):

you can try http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#steps demo, just change the values with your percentage and on input element events, you write the code to show / hide the slider.